# enable pjsip log config android

Tags: android

I've created an android app using pjsip, and I don't know how to enable pjsip logs to see them in android logcat.I wanna see things like INVITE, from , to . I have the classes LogCOnfig, Log Entry ,LogWriter.

Comment: Are you compile `pjsip` with logs enabled?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to find out. I just received a project with pjsip already compiled. But in my console (when i start a call) I cannot see any of these pjsip logs (like the Invite, Via, Max-Forward infos).

Comment: See my answer in different thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46052074/7430250).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `pjsip` i'm using custom class that `extends org.pjsip.pjsua2.LogWriter` 
To set logger to `EpConfig`

```
 mEpConfig!!.logConfig.level = 4
 mEpConfig!!.logConfig.consoleLevel = 5
 val mLogConfig = mEpConfig!!.logConfig
 mLogConfig.writer = CustomLogger()
 mLogConfig.decor = mLogConfig.decor and
                (pj_log_decoration.PJ_LOG_HAS_CR.swigValue().toLong()
                        or pj_log_decoration.PJ_LOG_HAS_NEWLINE.swigValue().toLong()).inv()
```

Comment: Great answer. But I would add an example of a simple LogWriter implementation:
`public class CustomLogger extends LogWriter {
    @Override
    public void write(LogEntry entry) {
        Log.d("CustomLogger", entry.getMsg());
    }
}`

It is also worth paying attention to the problem of non-obvious garbage collection https://stackoverflow.com/a/38525053/4398606