# pjsip log configs are not shown android

Tags: java, android

Using pjsip (in android) I just want my console to log something like this :

```
    <--- Received SIP request (541 bytes) from UDP:127.0.0.1:5061 --->
INVITE sip:service@127.0.0.1:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5061;branch=z9hG4bK-27600-1-0
From: breakfast <sip:eggowaffles@127.0.0.1:5061>;tag=27600SIPpTag001
To: sut <sip:service@127.0.0.1>
Call-ID: 1-27600@127.0.0.1
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Contact: sip:eggowaffles@127.0.0.1:5061
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   163

v=0
o=user1 53655765 2353687637 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
m=audio 6000 RTP/AVP 0
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=ptime:20
```

I already have enabled levels :

```
epConfig.getLogConfig().setLevel(5);
    epConfig.getLogConfig().setConsoleLevel(5);
```

What should I do to see those logs in my console or somewhere else ?

Comment: Do you use Android Studio or Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of `LogWriter`:

```
public class SipLogWriter extends LogWriter {
    @Override
    public void write(LogEntry entry) {
        Log.d(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + entry.getMsg());
    }
}
```

Override your log level settings with:

```
epConfig.getLogConfig().setLevel(4);
epConfig.getLogConfig().setConsoleLevel(4);
```

"epConfig" is your endpoint. Then you want to set log configuration:

```
SipLogWriter logWriter;
LogConfig log_cfg = epConfig.getLogConfig();
        logWriter = new SipLogWriter();
        log_cfg.setWriter(logWriter);
        log_cfg.setDecor(log_cfg.getDecor() & ~(pj_log_decoration.PJ_LOG_HAS_CR.swigValue() | pj_log_decoration.PJ_LOG_HAS_NEWLINE.swigValue()));
```

If you use Android Studio open Android Monitor for debug. Use logcat and track on "Debug". You can also filter on simply "sip" in search/filter field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's really helpful . I've checked the sip website and found almost the same thing . Anyway, it's perfect now :)